# How to increase yaxis on seaborn stripplot

Tags: python, seaborn, axes

I am trying to increase the number of y-ticks for a stripplot.

My code is:

```
g = sns.stripplot(data=flightdelays,x="delay", y="schedtime", jitter=True, size=10)
```

I understand that I cannot alter the y-axis using the available commands within stripplot.

The y-axis is the scheduled time in 24-hour form. Is someone able to show me how to set the yticks to every 100 i.e. every hour?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The seaborn plot returns an instance of a matplotlib axes object, which means that any matplotlib axes function can be called. So the solution here is:

```
g.set_ylim([min,max])
```